# How to call service or factory from AngularJS template?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code with variable:

```
<span>{{category}}</span>
```

Also I have service `CategoryService` with method `get()` that returns me string name of category.
How I can use this method in template like as:

```
<span>{{category | CategoryService.get}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers connect the model and the view. You'll want a function in your controller that, in turn, calls the service:

```
$scope.getCategory = function(CategoryService) {
    var cat = CategoryService.get();
    return cat;
});
```

Then you'd call that function from your view:

```
<span>{{getCategory()}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a controller for the web page:

```
<div ng-controller="OneCtrl">
<span>{{category }}</span>
</div>
```

And inside the controller I call the service:

```
myApp.controller("OneCtrl", ['$scope', '$location','$window', 'CategoryService',
  function($scope, $location,$window, CategoryService) {

    $scope.category = CategoryService.get();

  }
]);
```

Comment: I need call from template

Comment: @Ahmed You will need a controller to inject your service into. So you can't do this without a controller somewhere.